# Search by range in mongoDB with $gte $lt, problem with types in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with types when using search by range of dates with $gte and $lt.

types for my model:

```
export interface IOneStoreCa {
  magId: number,
  caTtc?: number,
  marge?: number,
}
export interface ICa {
  _id: string,
  data: IOneStoreCa[],
  date: Date,
  margeGlobal: number,
  totalCa: number,
}
```

my search query

```
const checkIfExists = await Ca.find({ date: { $gte: moment(e).startOf('day').toString(), $lt: moment(e).endOf('day').toString() } });
```

typescript error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callback?: Callback<(Document<any, any, ICa> & ICa)[]> | undefined): Query<(Document<any, any, ICa> & ICa)[], Document<any, any, ICa> & ICa, {}, ICa>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ date: { $gte: string; $lt: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<(Document<any, any, ICa> & ICa)[]>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'date' does not exist in type 'Callback<(Document<any, any, ICa> & ICa)[]>'.ts(2769)
```

Comment: pls provide reproducable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export interface IOneStoreCa {
  magId: number,
  caTtc?: number,
  marge?: number,
}
export interface ICa {
  _id: string,
  data: IOneStoreCa[],
  date: Date | string,
  margeGlobal: number,
  totalCa: number,
}
```

I had to change simply the type to union type Date | string